# What is Difference between this word: encountered and found

Tags: word-meaning

I trying Understand this word "encountered" and "found" ?

for example :

```
I found a girl
```

and

```
 I encountered a girl
```

Comment: If you google those two words, you will find numerous definitions, explanations and examples of their use.

Comment: I foud and I don't understand well , for this I question here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**encounter** refers to seeing or meeting something or someone in the course of your day, trip, travels, or journey, etc.  **find** refers to discovering something. But the two words are often used as close synonyms.

We *encounter* things and people that are in our path, with whom we might interact, as an encounter has duration, even if it be brief. We *find* things which we did not expect to be there, or which come to us by good fortune, or which we have been actively searching for.

> We encountered many fallen trees along the road.
>
> We found many fallen trees along the road.
>
> We encountered protesters in the lobby.
>
> We found protesters in the lobby.
>
> We found Tabby high up in a tree.
>
> I've found this girl. She's truly a gem. I hope this lasts.
>
> I've found this girl. She'd be perfect for the shampoo ad.

We would probably not *encounter* Tabby high up in a tree. What were we doing up there in the first place?

Comment: OMG now I understand well its used

Answer (score 2):

The use of these words depends upon your intention.

For example, if you have been looking for a girl who shares your interests then you might say:  **I found a girl who shares my love of soccer.**

Now look at the next sentence below:

**I encountered a girl in the men's lavatory.**

In this sentence you were not specifically looking to find a girl in the men's lavatory but unexpectedly, and by chance, found one there.

Some people might consider the use of encountered as being formal, but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: OMG now I understand well its used